# UICollectionView repeat labels and images on some cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating app like facebook so there is a problem that i want different number of images on collectionviewcell and i also had a polling option so no of polls can be produced.

**Things i have tried :**

`addSubView:` this option works but as cell is reused multiple overlays are generated and weird result.

Other option i think of is creating different cells in storyboard but that will result in in about 20 to 25 cells really bad idea.

Then i tried initwithframe: option but i am not able to manage different number of images on single cell. So not possible.

Here is my current code :

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstCollectionViewCell
        // Configure the cell
        if feed[indexPath.row]["images"].arrayValue.count == 1 {
            let tapped:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedOnImage:")
            tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            var image1:UIImageView
            image1 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 56, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width*0.65))
            if feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["mediaType"].intValue == 1 {
                image1.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["imageURL"].stringValue), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
            }else{
                let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
                let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
                dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
                    let image = self.drawImage(UIImage(named: "play_button")!, inImage: self.thumbnailImageFromURL(NSURL(string: self.feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["imageURL"].stringValue)!))

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        image1.image = image
                    })
                })
            }
            image1.tag = 0
            image1.userInteractionEnabled = true
            image1.clipsToBounds = true
            image1.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
            image1.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.addSubview(image1)
        }else if feed[indexPath.row]["images"].arrayValue.count == 2 {
            let tapped:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedOnImage:")
            tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            let tapped2:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedOnImage:")
            tapped2.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            var image1:UIImageView
            image1 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 56, self.view.frame.size.width/2-2, self.view.frame.size.width*0.45))
            if feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["mediaType"].intValue == 1 {
                image1.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["imageURL"].stringValue), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
            }else{
                let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
                let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
                dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
                    let image = self.drawImage(UIImage(named: "play_button")!, inImage: self.thumbnailImageFromURL(NSURL(string: self.feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["imageURL"].stringValue)!))

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        image1.image = image
                    })
                })
            }
            image1.tag = 0
            image1.userInteractionEnabled = true
            image1.clipsToBounds = true
            image1.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
            image1.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.addSubview(image1)
            var image2:UIImageView
            image2 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2+2, 56, self.view.frame.size.width/2-2, self.view.frame.size.width*0.45))
            if feed[indexPath.row]["images"][1]["mediaType"].intValue == 1 {
                image2.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feed[indexPath.row]["images"][1]["imageURL"].stringValue), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
            }else{
                let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
                let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
                dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
                    let image = self.drawImage(UIImage(named: "play_button")!, inImage: self.thumbnailImageFromURL(NSURL(string: self.feed[indexPath.row]["images"][1]["imageURL"].stringValue)!))

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        image2.image = image
                    })
                })
            }
            image2.tag = 1
            image2.userInteractionEnabled = true
            image2.clipsToBounds = true
            image2.addGestureRecognizer(tapped2)
            image2.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.addSubview(image2)
        }else if feed[indexPath.row]["images"].arrayValue.count == 3 {
            let tapped:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedOnImage:")
            tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            let tapped2:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedOnImage:")
            tapped2.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            let tapped3:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedOnImage:")
            tapped3.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            var image1:UIImageView
            image1 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 56, self.view.frame.size.width/2-2, (self.view.frame.size.width*0.45)/2 - 2))
            if feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["mediaType"].intValue == 1 {
                image1.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["imageURL"].stringValue), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
            }else{
                let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
                let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
                dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
                    let image = self.drawImage(UIImage(named: "play_button")!, inImage: self.thumbnailImageFromURL(NSURL(string: self.feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["imageURL"].stringValue)!))

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        image1.image = image
                    })
                })
            }
            image1.tag = 0
            image1.userInteractionEnabled = true
            image1.clipsToBounds = true
            image1.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
            image1.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.addSubview(image1)
            var image2:UIImageView
            image2 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2+2, 56, self.view.frame.size.width/2-2, self.view.frame.size.width*0.45))
            if feed[indexPath.row]["images"][1]["mediaType"].intValue == 1 {
                image2.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feed[indexPath.row]["images"][1]["imageURL"].stringValue), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
            }else{
                let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
                let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
                dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
                    let image = self.drawImage(UIImage(named: "play_button")!, inImage: self.thumbnailImageFromURL(NSURL(string: self.feed[indexPath.row]["images"][1]["imageURL"].stringValue)!))

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        image2.image = image
                    })
                })
            }
            image2.tag = 1
            image2.userInteractionEnabled = true
            image2.clipsToBounds = true
            image2.addGestureRecognizer(tapped2)
            image2.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.addSubview(image2)
            var image3:UIImageView
            image3 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 56+(self.view.frame.size.width*0.45)/2 + 2, self.view.frame.size.width/2-2, (self.view.frame.size.width*0.45)/2 - 2))
            if feed[indexPath.row]["images"][2]["mediaType"].intValue == 1 {
                image3.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feed[indexPath.row]["images"][2]["imageURL"].stringValue), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
            }else{
                let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
                let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
                dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
                    let image = self.drawImage(UIImage(named: "play_button")!, inImage: self.thumbnailImageFromURL(NSURL(string: self.feed[indexPath.row]["images"][2]["imageURL"].stringValue)!))

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        image3.image = image
                    })
                })
            }
            image3.tag = 2
            image3.userInteractionEnabled = true
            image3.clipsToBounds = true
            image3.addGestureRecognizer(tapped3)
            image3.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.addSubview(image3)
        }else if feed[indexPath.row]["images"].arrayValue.count == 4 {
            let tapped:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedOnImage:")
            tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            let tapped2:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedOnImage:")
            tapped2.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            let tapped3:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedOnImage:")
            tapped3.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            let tapped4:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedOnImage:")
            tapped4.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            var image1:UIImageView
            image1 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 56, self.view.frame.size.width/2-2, (self.view.frame.size.width*0.45)/2 - 2))
            if feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["mediaType"].intValue == 1 {
                image1.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["imageURL"].stringValue), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
            }else{
                let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
                let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
                dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
                    let image = self.drawImage(UIImage(named: "play_button")!, inImage: self.thumbnailImageFromURL(NSURL(string: self.feed[indexPath.row]["images"][0]["imageURL"].stringValue)!))

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        image1.image = image
                    })
                })
            }
            image1.tag = 0
            image1.userInteractionEnabled = true
            image1.clipsToBounds = true
            image1.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
            image1.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.addSubview(image1)
            var image2:UIImageView
            image2 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2+2, 56, self.view.frame.size.width/2-2, (self.view.frame.size.width*0.45)/2 - 2))
            if feed[indexPath.row]["images"][1]["mediaType"].intValue == 1 {
                image2.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feed[indexPath.row]["images"][1]["imageURL"].stringValue), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
            }else{
                let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
                let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
                dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
                    let image = self.drawImage(UIImage(named: "play_button")!, inImage: self.thumbnailImageFromURL(NSURL(string: self.feed[indexPath.row]["images"][1]["imageURL"].stringValue)!))

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        image2.image = image
                    })
                })
            }
            image2.tag = 1
            image2.userInteractionEnabled = true
            image2.clipsToBounds = true
            image2.addGestureRecognizer(tapped2)
            image2.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.addSubview(image2)
            var image3:UIImageView
            image3 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 56+(self.view.frame.size.width*0.45)/2 + 2, self.view.frame.size.width/2-2, (self.view.frame.size.width*0.45)/2 - 2))
            if feed[indexPath.row]["images"][2]["mediaType"].intValue == 1 {
                image3.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feed[indexPath.row]["images"][2]["imageURL"].stringValue), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
            }else{
                let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
                let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
                dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
                    let image = self.drawImage(UIImage(named: "play_button")!, inImage: self.thumbnailImageFromURL(NSURL(string: self.feed[indexPath.row]["images"][2]["imageURL"].stringValue)!))

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        image3.image = image
                    })
                })
            }
            image3.tag = 2
            image3.userInteractionEnabled = true
            image3.clipsToBounds = true
            image3.addGestureRecognizer(tapped3)
            image3.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.addSubview(image3)
            var image4:UIImageView
            image4 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2+2, 56+(self.view.frame.size.width*0.45)/2 + 2, self.view.frame.size.width/2-2, (self.view.frame.size.width*0.45)/2 - 2))
            if feed[indexPath.row]["images"][1]["mediaType"].intValue == 1 {
                image4.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feed[indexPath.row]["images"][1]["imageURL"].stringValue), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
            }else{
                let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
                let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
                dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
                    let image = self.drawImage(UIImage(named: "play_button")!, inImage: self.thumbnailImageFromURL(NSURL(string: self.feed[indexPath.row]["images"][3]["imageURL"].stringValue)!))

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        image4.image = image
                    })
                })
            }
            image4.tag = 3
            image4.userInteractionEnabled = true
            image4.clipsToBounds = true
            image4.addGestureRecognizer(tapped4)
            image4.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.addSubview(image4)
        }
        cell.profile.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feed[indexPath.row]["profilePic"].stringValue), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "profileplaceholder"))
        cell.name.text = feed[indexPath.row]["name"].stringValue
        cell.time.text = feed[indexPath.row]["postedTime"].stringValue
        if feed[indexPath.row]["totalFlowers"].stringValue == "" {
            cell.flowerLabel.text = "0 flowers"
        }else{
            cell.flowerLabel.text = "\(feed[indexPath.row]["totalFlowers"].intValue) flowers"
        }
        if feed[indexPath.row]["totalHelpful"].stringValue == "" {
            cell.helpfulLabel.text = "0 Helpful"
        }else{
            cell.helpfulLabel.text = "\(feed[indexPath.row]["totalHelpful"].intValue) helpful"
        }
        if feed[indexPath.row]["totalComments"].stringValue == "" {
            cell.commentLabel.text = "0 Comments"
        }else{
            cell.commentLabel.text = "\(feed[indexPath.row]["totalComments"].intValue) Comments"
        }
        cell.flower.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: why are you adding UIImageView at run time in cellForIndexPath, this will create new instance of UIImageView and will add to cell and this will keep doing and will cause to memory leak. You should add UIImageView and UILabel in collectionViewCell in StoryBoard and access the imageView and assign imageView.Image = image same things with label you should do.

Comment: Please see the code again i want different number of imageviews depending on json. And this is not just imageviews further there will be polling option with same condition. How many cells will i made? Maybe 20 or 30 that's pointless

Answer (score 1):

When you display some rows on your device, these rows are filled with data. Imagine that your images are A/B/C etc.

```
Row1   A - -
Row2   A B -
Row3   - B C
etc
```

When you scroll, new values of the cells are calculated and drawn. The ViewController calculates these rows based on the previous value.

In the old situation on row1 only image A was displayed.
You want to display only image C. So you add C to the cell.
The view controller will take row A, and add image C resulting in:

```
Row1   A - C     // Both images A and B displayed!
```

The solution is simple. You have to clear the images before you add them!

Answer (score 1):

It's because toy `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` it's a right way but iOS reuse created cells when scrolling, so thats mean you need to clear content before you will set new.

And would be better if do it in `collectionView willDisplay Cell` in this delegate method you can retrieve already created cell